# how i can get purchased Angular project index file or home page

Tags: indexing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS0Ym.jpg)   i have purchased windows angular project and download the project. But in that rar file index or home file not availble only .DS.Store file only is there how i can get vs file

i need step by step procedure or video link YouTube